# How to get only the data with slash and the number behind it?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have the following table and data

```
CREATE TABLE arch (
id INT NOT NULL,
arch_number VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO arch 
(id, arch_number) 
VALUES 
(1,"AN 50"),
(2,"AN 50/0"),
(3,"AN 50/1"),

(4,"AN 51/0"),
(5,"AN 51/1"),

(6,"AN 52/1"),

(7,"AN 53/2");
```

I want to select only those arch_numbers that have **only** slashes with numbers behind them. That means in this example I want to get AN 51,AN 52 and AN 53. AN 50 should be ignored completely.

My Sql doesnt work like this:

```
select * from arch where arch_number like '%/%'
```

With this I will get every AN including AN 50. However, in this case AN 50 should be ignored because the row with id=1 has one without a slash and number.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select a.*
from arch a
where not exists (select 1
                  from arch a2
                  where a2.arch_number not like '%/%' and
                        a.arch_number like a2.arch_number || '/%'
                 );
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. Your code would give me this: 1|AN 50
4|AN 51/0
5|AN 51/1
6|AN 52/1
7|AN 53/2 However, I dont want AN 50.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSTR` function to get row data, which  don't exist `/`  on `arch_number` column, then `not exists` subquery to filter `arch_number` didn't contain `/`

```
SELECT *
FROM arch t
WHERE not exists (
  select *
  from arch t1
  where INSTR(t1.arch_number,'/',1,1) = 0 
    and t.arch_number like '%' || t1.arch_number || '%'
);
```

sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c56df/26